# How to create a temporary user account on OS X

Tags: linux, ssh, mac, user-profiles

I want to create one or more user accounts in OS X that operate similar, but not the same, to a Guest user account in OS X:

> Files created by a guest are stored in a temporary folder, but that
> folder and its contents are deleted when the guest logs out.

https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/set-up-other-users-on-your-mac-mtusr001/mac

However, Guest user accounts do not allow SSH access, and there are other limitations.

My goal is:

- Login through SSH with a temporary profile that resets/removes at logoff.
- Be able to login to the same user account through SSH multiple times, simultaneously and have each get a temporary and separate profile.

The idea is to provide a temporary working environment for an automated process to connect thru SSH, run some commands (building an iOS app), then logoff. And, it needs to be able to do it in parallel, and have a "clean" environment on each session.

Is there any mechanism through which to do this in OS X? Maybe some type of Linux equivalent I can look in to?

Comment: What you're asking for kind of goes against the whole concept of what a Unix user account *is*. If you want to set up a Mac as a remote, automated, on-demand build server for iOS builds, there are probably better ways to do that. Look at how any CI/CD system (any one that supports Macs as build servers) handles it.

Comment: Otherwise, I'd give a hand-wavy answer that you could make the account's login shell be a script instead of a shell, and have the script spin up a Docker container with a Docker-OSX image (macOS inside a Docker container), and have the script get to a shell inside the Docker container. Then have the script stop the Docker container (and do any other needed cleanup) on logout. And maybe also write some other scriptage, maybe triggered from a cron job, to clean up anything that gets left around when things go wrong.

Comment: @Spiff that’s a great idea. A bit more complex than I was hoping. But I had considered something like this. If I needed that kind of isolation it would justify it more, but it’s not a requirement here. Maybe I will explore this idea more. The key is making it run a script on login, which I was particularly aware of but it makes sense by configuring that as the “shell.”